# How to create JSON array using JQuery for cloned table rows

Tags: jquery, json

I have a table in my HTML page and the row of the table gets cloned on focus out. When I click on submit button I have to write JQuery script to iterate through all the table rows and create a JSON array which I would send to the controller using ajax call. Can anyone please help me out with the JQuery code to iterate through the cloned table rows and create a JSON array out of it.

Here is my HTML table

```
<form class="allergyrow">
        <table id="tab" border="1" width="1000">
            <thead >
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Remove</th>
                    <th scope="col">Allergy</th>
                    <th scope="col">Reaction</th>
                    <th scope="col">Adverse Event Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Comment</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="datarow">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remove" class="remove" value="Remove" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="myText" class="myText"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <table id="inner" class="inner">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="innerrow">
                                        <td>
                                            <select id="myList" class="myList">
                                                <option value="1">Rashes</option>
                                                <option value="2">Shock</option>
                                                <option value="3">Asthma</option>
                                                <option value="4">Nausea</option>
                                                <option value="5">Anemia</option>
                                                <option value="6">Unknown/Other</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select class="reaction">
                                                <option>Yes</option>
                                                <option>Mild</option>
                                                <option>Moderate</option>
                                                <option>severe</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button class="plus">plus</button>

                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button class="minus">minus</button>                                        
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" id="eventdate" class="eventdate" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="comment" class="comment" />
                    </td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Here is my JQuery code to clone the table rows

```
$("#comment").live('focusout',function(){
                count++;
                if(count<10)
                {               
                var row=$("#tab > tbody > tr:last").clone(true).insertAfter("#tab > tbody > tr:last"); 
                $(".myText",row).val('');

                $("#remove",row).hide();
                $(".myList", row).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $(".reaction", row).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $(".eventdate", row).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $(".eventdate", row).val('');
                $(".comment", row).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $(".comment",row).val('');
                $(".plus", row).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
```

I have Jquery code for on Submit but it only catches the first row and not all the cloned table rows.

```
$("button").click(function(){

        var removed=$('#remove').val();
        var allergy=$('#myText').val();
        var reaction=$('#myList').val();
        var severity=$('#reaction').val();
        var eventDate=$('#eventdate').val();
        var comment=$('#comment').val();
        var info={
                   removed : removed,
                   allergy : allergy,
                   reaction: reaction,
                   severity: severity,
                   eventDate: eventDate,
                   comment : comment};
          });
```

If anyone can tell me how to iterate through all the table rows and create a JSON array I would be really grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var data={};
        $('table').find('tr').each(function(){
            var id=$(this).attr('id');
            var row={};
            $(this).find('input,select,textarea').each(function(){
                row[$(this).attr('name')]=$(this).val();
            });
            data[id]=row;
        });
        console.log(data);
```

Somewhat like this you will have to do..

Comment: Hello,I have tried the above code. The control doesn't go into the each loop. Its finding all the table rows but doesn't loop through them.